# Groups audience list shows NONE in Organic Group

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, organic-groups

In my drupal site i have implemented the [Organic Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module for user group management

1. Here I have created a number of groups like grp1, grp2 ... .
2. I have a custom content type as **Opinion** that has a field **Groups audience** with FIELD TYPE **Entity Reference** so that user can able to post the content type and choose group from **GROUPS AUDIENCE** to which group the post should belong

The issue is when i am adding **Opinion** by admin dashboard  the groups are showing in the list **GROUPS AUDIENCE** as  grp1, grp2 ... and posted to that required group

But when the authenticated user want to post that the **GROUPS AUDIENCE** shows **NONE** , by which after posting the content it is visible in  Home page but not showing the corresponding group page

I have gone through  [this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1872136)

Also given the full permission to the Role that assigned to the user . Any guidance will help me a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the following to get my work 
Admin -> structure -> content type -> custom content type(i.e. Opinion) -> manage fields -> changed the **WIDGET** name to **Select list** of the field name having **FIELD TYPE** as **Entity Reference**